# What is general solution of the PDE $(x^2+y^2)u_x+2xyu_y=-u^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What is the general solution of the following PDE?

> $$(x^2+y^2)u_x+2xyu_y=-u^2.$$

If we write the characteristic equation
$$\frac{dx}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{-du}{u^2}$$
then, we find $\frac{d(x+y)}{(x+y)^2}=\frac{-du}{u^2}$ and we have $c_1=1/u+1/(x+y)$.

And then?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{dx+dy}{(x+y)^2}=\frac{dx-dy}{(x-y)^2}
$$
$$\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{1}{x-y}=c_2$$
With the first characteristic equation that you alredy found, this second equation (or any other equivalent equation) allows to express the general solution.

Comment: From your second characteristic , we find $c_2=0$ . We know $f(c_2)=c_1$ , then $f(0)=1/u+1/(x+y)$. Is there a problem?

Comment: Why do you think that $c_2=0$ ? It is any value and $c_1$ as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did a mistake while calculating $\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{1}{x-y}=\frac{x-y-(x+y)}{(x+y)(x-y)}=0=c_2$

Comment: I found $c_2=-2y/(x^2-y^2)$ and $u=\frac{x+y}{(x+y)f(\frac{-2y}{x^2-y^2})-1}$ where $f$  is an arbitrary funct. Right?

Comment: Well done ! ...